# Socket.io sessionStore, store.get method doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, passport.js

I am trying to use session storage with Socket.io and passport.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var sessionStore = session({
    store: new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost/RULE'}),
    key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'Heisenberg'
});

// Socket.io auth
io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'Heisenberg',
    store: sessionStore,
    success: onAuthorizeSuccess,
    fail: onAuthorizeFail,
}));
```

I get this error: 
`TypeError: auth.store.get is not a function`

So I guess it's a problem with the `connect-mongo` store instance, but I do not how to debug it or what the problem could be.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the problem was that I was serving the `express session` instead of the `MongoStore`

```
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
// sessionStore and expressSesion are now saved distinctly
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost/RULE'});
var expressSession = session({
    store: sessionStore,
    key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'ThisIsTheSecret'
});

var passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio');

// Load middlewares
var morgan = require('morgan');

// Use middlewares
app.use(expressSession);

// Socket.io auth
io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'ThisIsTheSecret',
    store: sessionStore, // here we pass the MongoStore, not the expressSession
    success: onAuthorizeSuccess,
    fail: onAuthorizeFail,
}));
```